# All Communities Loader - making better use of the /users/hidecommunities page

Tags: script, tampermonkey

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: screenshot of all visible communities list]

### About

All Communities Loader is a script for enhancing the `/users/hidecommunities` page by listing *all* communities instead of only 12 at a time (inspired by [this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375368/786798)), as well as making better use of the available viewport space via smaller rows for the visible communities list.

#### License

The script is licensed under the [GPL-3.0-or-later](https://spdx.org/licenses/GPL-3.0-or-later) license.

#### Download

[Install](https://github.com/userscripters/all-communities-loader/raw/master/dist/modern/index.user.js) | [Minified](https://github.com/userscripters/all-communities-loader/raw/master/dist/modern/index.min.user.js)

#### Platform

Version number means "last tested on":

| Chrome | Opera | Firefox | Edge | IE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ✔ 97.0.4692.71 | ✔ 82.0.4227.43 | - | - | no |

### Contact

Author: [Oleg Valter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11407695/oleg-valter)

Organization: [UserScripters](https://github.com/userscripters)

Please, submit bug reports [on the source repository](https://github.com/userscripters/all-communities-loader/issues)

Before adding a new one, please check if it hasn't been raised before.

You can also [drop by to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214345/userscript-newbies-and-friends), we are a friendly bunch.

### Code

[Source code](https://github.com/userscripters/all-communities-loader/blob/master/src/index.ts) written in TypeScript.

Uses:

- [type definitions](https://stackapps.com/q/9063/78873) for Stack Exchange global objects;
- [type definitions](https://stackapps.com/q/9162/78873) for the Stack Exchange API;
- userscript manager [metadata block generator](https://stackapps.com/q/9088/78873).

Contributions are welcome, you can always [submit a PR here](https://github.com/userscripters/all-communities-loader/pulls).