# Userscripts Configurer - One script to configure them all

Tags: script, posts

### Screenshot

[image: Configurer UI with example options for several test userscripts]

### About

UserScripts Configurer is a shared configuration controller for UserScripters' userscripts.

#### How to use

Configurer is exposed as a global accessible via `UserScripters.Userscripts.Configurer`.
To ensure the Configurer is done loading, including scripts are encouraged to listen to a `userscript-configurer-load` event on `unsafeWindow` before hooking:

```ts
unsafeWindow.addEventListener("userscript-configurer-load", () => {
    // it is safe to hook into the configurer now
});
```

To hook to the Configurer, call its `register` method with the name of the userscript as its first parameter:

```ts
const configurer = UserScripters.Userscripts.Configurer;
const script = configurer.register("Auto Review Comments");
```

Since v1.6.0, the Configurer supports storage overrides if you pass a storage (either a userscript manager storage or a `localStorage`) as the second parameter to its `register` method.
If passed, the configuration will be stored in the corresponding storage instead of the in-built Configurer storage.

The method will return an instance of `Userscript` to which options (if any) can be added by calling its `option` method with 2 parameters. The 1<sup>st</sup> is the option's name, the 2<sup>nd</sup> is its configuration. The configurer currently supports 4 types of options (`type` field):

- text input
- checkboxes
- toggle switch
- select

If you want to ensure a `Userscript` or an `Option` is registered only once, both classes have a `has` method that accepts a `name` and returns a `boolean`:

```ts
// ensure the script hasn't been registered
if(!configurer.has("my-script")) {
    configurer.register("my-script");
}

// ensure the option hasn't been registered
if(!script.has("my-option") {
    script.option("my-option", { type: "text" });
}
```

Option config interface (as well as the interface of the Configurer itself) is described by our [Global Types](https://github.com/userscripters/global-types) type definitions package.

```ts
// text input option
script.option(
    "welcome-text",
    {
        def: "Welcome to Stack Overflow",
        title: "Greeting text",
        type: "text",
    }
);

// checkbox option
script.option("prefer-diff-view", {
    items: [{
        label: "Use diff view",
        value: true
    }],
    type: "checkbox",
});

//toggle option
script.option("prefer-diff-view", {
    direction: "left", // aligns levers to the left of the title
    selected: true,
    title: "Prefer diff view",
    type: "toggle",
});

// select option
script.option("style", {
    items: [
        { label: "Simple", value: "simple" },
        { label: "Full", value: "full", selected: true }
    ],
    title: "Reference style",
    type: "select",
});
```

---

As of version 2.0.0, options can have disabled state conditions ensuring a given option can be dynamically disabled based on the values of other options.
To add conditions, pass a `disabledWhen` dictionary to the option config. The dictionary is keyed on option *names* with values corresponding to one of the options' values.
When the value of the option specified in the dictionary matches the one in storage, the option the dictionary belongs to will be disabled and vice versa otherwise.
An example option configuration looks like this:

```
// an option that will be disabled if 'prefer-diff-view' is false
script.option("dependent", {
    disabledWhen: {
        ["prefer-diff-view"]: false,
    },
    title: "Dependent option",
    type: "toggle",
});
```

Options can be added in bulk as a record of name-config pairs via the `options` method. An optional second parameter can provide shared config options:

```ts
script.options({
    welcome: {
        def: "Welcome to Stack Overflow",
        title: "Greeting text",
    },
}, {
    type: "text",
});
```

On value change, the Configurer dispatches a custom *bubbling* event on the registered script's `container` with the following `detail`:

```ts
interface ChangeEventDetail {
    name: string,
    script: string,
    oldValue: string | boolean | string[],
    value: string | boolean | string[],
}
```

The custom event can be listened to via the `userscript-configurer-change` event name:

```ts
window.addEventListener("userscript-configurer-change", ({ detail }) => {
    // do something with the change data
});
```

---

As of version 2.1.0, end users can configure where the button toggling the options modal will be rendered in the UI:

[image: configuration option for choosing the controller button position]

By default, the button is still displayed in the sidebar slightly above the expandable modal. There are 2 other options users can choose instead:

1. As an icon button in the top navigation bar

   [image: top navigation bar icon button position]
2. As a link button in the footer under the "Data" link in the "Stack Exchange Network" column

   [image: footer button position]

---

The Configurer uses a [userscript manager-agnostic storage](https://github.com/userscripters/storage) that also works with `localStorage` if manager storages are inaccessible.

#### License

The script is licensed under the [GPL-3.0-or-later](https://spdx.org/licenses/GPL-3.0-or-later) license.

#### Download

Latest version: 2.1.1

[Install](https://github.com/userscripters/userscripts-configurer/raw/master/dist/modern/index.user.js) | [Minified](https://github.com/userscripters/userscripts-configurer/raw/master/dist/modern/index.min.user.js)

#### Platform

Version number means "last tested on":

| Chrome | Edge | Explorer | Firefox | Opera |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ✔ 100.0.4896.127 | - | - | - | - |

Supported userscript managers:

- Greasemonkey
- Tampermonkey
- Violentmonkey

### Contact

Author: Oleg Valter

Organization: [UserScripters](https://github.com/userscripters)

Please, submit bug reports [on the source repository](https://github.com/userscripters/userscripts-configurer/issues).

Before adding a new one, please check if it hasn't been raised before.

You can also [drop by to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214345), we are a friendly bunch.

### Code

[Source code](https://github.com/userscripters/userscripts-configurer/blob/master/src/index.ts) is written in TypeScript.

Contributions are welcome, you can always [submit a PR here](https://github.com/userscripters/userscripts-configurer/pulls).