# Magic Answer References - a userscript for making proper post referencing easier

Tags: script, posts

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: reference workflow animation]

### About

Referencing other posts properly by hand is tedious: one has to link to users' profiles as usernames are subject to change any time, as well as to their post. Magic Answer References userscript makes all this as easy as clicking a button! It adds a button to the editor (right next to the Stacks Snippet one) that opens a referencing modal.

The modal contains a *sortable* table with brief information about the question and every answer on the current page with a full-text case-insensitive search input below for filtering.

If one wants to reference a post not from another page or even another Stack Exchange site, they can simply paste a link to the post in the search modal, and the post will be added to the table.

Since v2.2.0 also works for inline editors added after the initial page load when entering edit mode.

#### License

The script is licensed under the [GPL-3.0-or-later](https://spdx.org/licenses/GPL-3.0-or-later) license.

#### Download

[Install](https://github.com/userscripters/magic-answer-references/raw/master/dist/modern/index.user.js) | [Minified](https://github.com/userscripters/magic-answer-references/raw/master/dist/modern/index.min.user.js)

#### Platform

Version number means "last tested on":

| Chrome | Opera | Firefox | Edge | IE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ✔ 100.0.4896.127 | - | ✔ 99.0.1 | - | no |

### Contact

Author: [Oleg Valter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11407695/oleg-valter)

Organization: [UserScripters](https://github.com/userscripters)

Please, submit bug reports [on the source repository](https://github.com/userscripters/magic-answer-references/issues).

Before adding a new one, please check if it hasn't been raised before.

You can also [drop by to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214345/userscript-newbies-and-friends), we are a friendly bunch.

### Code

[Source code](https://github.com/userscripters/magic-answer-references/blob/master/src/index.ts) written in TypeScript.

Uses:

- [type definitions](https://stackapps.com/q/9063/78873) for Stack Exchange global objects;
- [type definitions](https://stackapps.com/q/9162/78873) for the Stack Exchange API;
- userscript manager-agnostic [storage](https://github.com/userscripters/storage).
- userscript manager [metadata block generator](https://stackapps.com/q/9088/78873).

Contributions are welcome, you can always [submit a PR here](https://github.com/userscripters/magic-answer-references/pulls).